# Admin order designated to specific store based on user

Tags: magento

I am looking to eliminate the "Please Select a Store" step of the Magento admin order process by automatically setting the store/view based on the user logged into the admin area.

Is this possible? Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks
Chris

Comment: I don't think it would be possible since admin area is a store view itself. Basically orders needs to be connected with one of the frontend store views in order to keep track of the inventory, collect price and price rules and so on.